# AttributeError displayed as module 'spacy' has no attribute 'cli' while downloading spacy.cli.download('en_core_web_lg') on databricks

Tags: nlp, command-line-interface, attributeerror, spacy-3

I have written a code for NLP programme and downloading pipeline 'en_core_web_lg' using spacy, up to now the code was running but now it is showing me Attribute error

> module 'spacy' has no attribute 'cli'.

i have installed the pypi-cli version 0.4.1 and spacy 3.2.3 but still not able to figure out the root cause and solution of the problem.

i am new to the coding.